# Shared storage for both worker and webrole in azure

Tags: asp.net, azure-storage

Can i have shared temporary storage for both worker role and web role for an azure application ?

I have a video upload section in my application, and there on uploading an mp4 video it will stored in the LocalStorage of the web role from there i was generating the thumbnail of the video and also the video conversion to a different format. Initially i done this scenario using TPL from the web role itself. Now I am planning to handover the video conversion and thumbnail generation to worker-role. i. e , when a user uploads a video it will be stored in any temporary storage, the worker role picks it up and converts the video to another format and the thumbnail for the video is generated and the results will be uploaded to my blobstorage and the video will be deleted from the local storage.

As far as my knowledge is concerned the worker role cannot access the local storage of a webrole. So where should I store my video initially so that both worker and webrole can access it ?

Thanks in advance

Boney

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use blob storage?

Comment: Yes blobstorage is an option. But would it be slower than localstorage ? I don't need the  initial uploaded mp4 video once I generate the thumbnail and video gets converted and that's why I thought of temporary sotrage like local storage.

Comment: Yes, blob storage will probably be slower than local storage. That's because there's a network involved, but you have no choice about that. (You're trying to share a file between different servers, so there will always be a network.)